# JSP Bootstrap Div column issue

Tags: html, mysql, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

Good day! I am trying to generate different boxes in my page and I'm planning to have a layout that is something like this:

4x1 layout

But what happens to my file is that it generates boxes like this:

1x4 layout

When I do this hard coded, there are no problems. However, when I use scriptlets to get the values from my MySQL Database the problem appears. Any ideas on what I should do? Thank you!!! This is my code BTW:

```html
 <div class="content-wrapper">
<% EmployeeDAO personalInfo = new EmployeeDAO();%>
<% for (int i = 0; i < personalInfo.getAllPersonalInfo().size(); i++) {%>
<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 profile_details">
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h4 class="brief"><i>Digital Strategist</i></h4>
        <div class="left col-xs-7">
          <h2 id="applicantName<%=+i%>" id="applicantName<%=+i%>">
          <%=personalInfo.getAllPersonalInfo().get(i).getFirstName() + " "%><%=personalInfo.getAllPersonalInfo().get(i).getLastName()%>
          </h2>
          <p><strong>About: </strong> Web Designer / UX / Graphic Artist / Coffee Lover </p>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><i class="fa fa-building"></i> Address: </li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Phone #: </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right col-xs-5 text-center"> <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle img-responsive"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 bottom text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">
          <p class="ratings"> <a>4.0</a> <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a> <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a> <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a> <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a> <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star-o"></span></a> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"> <i class="fa fa-user"> </i> <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"  data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#AddTicket<%=+i%>"> <i class="fa fa-user"> </i> View Profile </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "I am trying to generate different boxes in my page and im planning to have a layout that is something like this:

Box Box Box Box

But what happens to my file is that it generates boxes like this:

Box Box Box Box"

Both are same right???

Comment: sorry, edited it already. stackoverflow textbox auto aligned it

Comment: Can you do this >> use scriptlets to get the values from MySQL database and right click on browser page > click on view page source and post the generated HTML here

Comment: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/gtBTK5l81C

Here is the link where I have copy pasted the source of the generated web page

Answer (score 0):

As I can see there are 2 issues in your code.

- If you want to loop 4 profile_details divs you should place the loop after row div since in bootstrap, "row" class define an actual row. With your code, you will get separate row for each profile_details.
- closing brackets for "for loop" is missing

Fix those things first and check